# Python: Take two list and make a new list by merging them

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, list, python-3.x

I have two list

```
list1 = ["john", "kelvin", "harry", "rob", "jenny", "donne", "justin", "sam", "peter", "kitty"]
list2 = ["radha", "mohan", "pankaj", "sikha", "samarth"]
```

I want to merge both the list in a way that I get a list of dictionaries in which there should be two people from list1 and 1 person from list2.

```
example = [{"john", "kelvin", "radha"}, {"harry", "rob", "mohan"}, ......]
```

Comment: if you want to make dictionary, where is the key?

Comment: group = []

for i in range((len(list1)+len(list2))/3):
 for j, k in Bteam,Pteam:
  gang = {}

Comment: not dictionary but a list of object like that example

Comment: Take a look at [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: @asongtoruin I am not getting that documentation. Can you implement it on given scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what should work for your example input:

```
list1 = ["john", "kelvin", "harry", "rob", "jenny", "donne", "justin", "sam", "peter", "kitty"]
list2 = ["radha", "mohan", "pankaj", "sikha", "samarth"]

list3 = []

for i in xrange(len(list2)):
    temp_list = [list1[2*i], list1[1+(2*i)], list2[i]]
    list3.append(temp_list)


print list3
```

working for `python 2.x`, just change the `print` statement to make it work in `python 3.x`

Cheers

> Here's the output:

`[['john', 'kelvin', 'radha'], ['harry', 'rob', 'mohan'], ['jenny', 'donne', 'pankaj'], ['justin', 'sam', 'sikha'], ['peter', 'kitty', 'samarth']]`

Comment: @amanroy, this will give you a nested list, which should be enough for your use :)

Comment: Thanks @TheDarkKnight.

Comment: Cool. nice use of odd/even indexing.

Answer (score 1):

List of sets with 2+1 elements:

```
ls1 = list("ABCDEF")
ls2 = list("123")

iterls1 = iter(ls1)
ls3 = [set(x) for x in zip(iterls1, iterls1, ls2)]
print(ls3)
# [{'A', '1', 'B'}, {'2', 'D', 'C'}, {'3', 'F', 'E'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

So just making a list as you said will actually end up being a list of sets (just to mention it).

```
output = []
for i in list2:
    output.append({i, list1.pop(), list1.pop()})
```

If you wanted a nested list just change the `{}` brackets to `[]`.

Also, this will empty list1, so if you choose to use this way and need `list1` later on, it'd be worth keeping a copy in memory.

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, it looks like you want to iterate from the start of `list1`. In that case, use `list1.pop(0)`, where the `0` is the index at which to pop from the list.

Comment: Won't this `pop` elements from the *end* of the array?

Comment: if that matters, you can just pass in the index you want to pop, so if you want to pop the start, just call `list1.pop(0)` instead

Comment: Looking at OP's example, I think that *is* the case :)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight ah cool, thanks for pointing that out! I'll edit my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["john", "kelvin", "harry", "rob", "jenny", "donne", "justin", "sam", "peter", "kitty"]
list2 = ["radha", "mohan", "pankaj", "sikha", "samarth"]

list3 = [[list1[2*i],list1[2*i+1],list2[i]] for i in xrange(len(list2))]
```

This should do it, use list comprehension it looks neater.

Answer (score 0):

VPfB's answer is really pythonic, with a nice use of `iter`.
Here's another variation in the same spirit:

```
list3 = list(map(set, zip(list1[::2], list1[1::2], list2)))
```

The main differences are:

- Use of `map` instead of list comprehension to cast the tuples generated by `zip` into sets.
- Use of slice instead of `iter`.